# Postgres - Select list of records and one row with total

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
with charges as (
    select some_fields, (sum(subtotal_cents) as total from my_table 
    where <condition>
    group by some_field
) 
select <some_fields>, charges.total
from my_table
<lots_of_joins!>
left join charges on <condition>
where <condition>
```

Assuming the sum was 100, this gives me the following output:

```
field_a | field_b | total
-----------------------
val1    | val2    | 100
val3    | val4    | 100
```

Would it be possible to instead get something like this (or close to it):

```
field_a | field_b | total
-----------------------
val1    | val2    | 
val3    | val4    | 
total   |         | 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using a UNION and some tricky order by stuff:

```
with charges as (
    select some_fields, (sum(subtotal_cents) as total from my_table 
    where <condition>
    group by some_field
) 
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        select <some_fields>, CAST(NULL AS INTEGER) AS TOTAL, 0 AS sortorder
        from my_table
        <lots_of_joins!>
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'total' as field_a, NULL as some_fields_2, NULL as some_fields_3, ..., charges.total, 1 as sortorder
    )
ORDER BY sortorder;
```

The important things here are:

1. We are using a UNION to stack the results of two queries (your query results and your CTE results)
2. The fields must line up between those two Union'd queries in both ordinal and type otherwise you will error out.
3. We add a new column for sort order, shove the whole beast into a subquery, and then ORDER BY the `sortorder` field so your CTE results are on the bottom of the UNION'd results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using `GROUPING SETS`. The [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) doesn't have much in the way of examples, but let's say you have a table with three columns: `a`, `b`, and `total`.

A simple group by will get you this:

```
# SELECT a, b, SUM(total) FROM foo GROUP BY a, b;
  a   |  b   | sum 
------+------+-----
 val1 | val2 | 100
 val3 | val4 | 100
```

That SQL is equivalent to `SELECT a, b, SUM(total) FROM foo GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((a, b))`. You can add to that list of grouping sets to get the total overall:

```
# SELECT a, b, SUM(total) FROM foo GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((a, b));
  a   |  b   | sum 
------+------+-----
 val1 | val2 | 100
 val3 | val4 | 100

# SELECT a, b, SUM(total) FROM foo GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((a, b), ());
  a   |  b   | sum 
------+------+-----
 val1 | val2 | 100
 val3 | val4 | 100
      |      | 200
```

Obviously, you'll have to adjust this for your more complicated use case, but it should be fairly straightforward.

**edit**: I've created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f87b9/1) with my simple example case.